# How to scroll to the right side to an element which is displayed in DOM only after the scroll? (Java Selenium)

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, scroll

Using Java selenium....I have to scroll to an element which is present at extreme right side of the page,

But the problem is this element appears in the DOM only after the scroll.

Tried the below code...

```java
WebElement scrollElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("some_xpath"));
List elements=driver.findElements(By.xpath("some_xpath"));

    for(WebElement el:elements)
    {
        System.out.println(el.getText());                   
        if(!el.getText().equalsIgnoreCase("element to be clicked") )
        {
            ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollLeft += 1000;", scrollElement);
            Thread.sleep(5000);
            elements=driver.findElements(By.xpath("some xpath"));
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        }
        else
        {
            el.click();
            Thread.sleep(5000);
            break;
        }
    
    }
```

The problem with above code is.... it fetches all table headers in first loop, after scroll happens, the list of table headers gets updated (thats the reason why i assigned value to elements again) But still m getting stale element exception.

scenario: imagine a table with 26 columns A to Z...

I want to access "T" column,

in first view...A to E columns are displayed and present in DOM

then after scrolling E to J columns are displayed and present in DOM

I have also reassigned elements again,

so that it gets the list of elements after the scroll...

but still m getting stale element exception...

**Update:**
Code worked when I used TAB instead of scroll..

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Imagine a table which has 50 columns...i want to get data from 50 th column which is at extreme right... The problem is that 50 th column is NOT yet present in DOM....i will have to scroll to that column for it to appear in the DOM

Answer (score 1):

```
while ( !element(yourElement).isPresent()) {
        js.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollLeft += 1000;", grid);
    }
```

Before the code, you define the grid as a `WebElement` where to scroll

You can experiment with the pixel (1000) number as well to see how much it scrolls. And yes, the command `arguments[0].scrollLeft` is to scroll right.

Comment: Actually selenium first tries searching for the target element in DOM, and the script fails . The element appears in the DOM only after i scroll

Comment: Well what I sent you shouldn't fail if it is not in dome, because the `isPresent()` method returns a boolean value, for the condition check

Comment: finally i was able to achieve and run a successful code by using tab instead of scroll....

Answer (score 1):

If "selenium first tries searching for the target element in DOM, else script fails" - Then Keep the java script executer in an 'IF' statement and not while.
Like:
If (The element is not visible)
perform java script executer